# Custom font icons are showing cross in box in react-native

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-vector-icons

I am trying to use Custom fonts in react native. Converted SVG's in custom icon set using Icomoon and tried all the steps from https://www.reactnative.guide/12-svg-icons-using-react-native-vector-icons/12.1-creating-custom-iconset.html.

`react-native-vector-icons` was installed already.

used `react-native link react-native-vector-icons` to setup the vector icons framework for the project.

Placed the selection.json and Icomoon.ttf files in `assets/fonts` folder.

And added  `"rnpm": { "assets": [ "resources/fonts" ] }` in package.json file

Created CustomIcon.js file and added

```
import {createIconSetFromIcoMoon} from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import icoMoonConfig from './selection.json';
export default createIconSetFromIcoMoon(icoMoonConfig);
```

In App.js file added following

```
import CustomIcon from './components/CustomIcon.js'

<CustomIcon name='accounts' size={50} /> //To use the icon
```

And the Icon is showing ☒ at the icon place.

If anyone have solution please share,
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using iOS or Android?

Comment: I am using Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried a lot but didn't get solution but finally I got the solution
whenever I used `react-native link react-native-vector-icons` command it didn't worked properly. So I checked font folder in `android/app/src/main/assets/font` and I found that my icomoon font file wasn't present there. So I copied the file and manually pasted at the location and it `worked` .

Comment: you can refer [link]https://www.reactnative.guide/12-svg-icons-using-react-native-vector-icons/12.1-creating-custom-iconset.html

Comment: Thanks for the guide but I haven't been able to manage it. Does that work with expo?

Answer (score 3):

In Android platform icon showed me like this:

[image]

after some time of troubleshouting I finally find out solution.

Beacouse of I use my own icon set I created iconSet.ttf from iconSet.svg by IcoMoon App.

In fact I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/bam-tech/add-custom-icons-to-your-react-native-application-f039c244386c

IcoMoon App created *.ttf and selection.json and **problem was** in selection.json.

I renamed *.ttf file to myIcons.ttf but I **had to** change **fontFamily** and **name** in the end of file selection.json to same name like I named *.ttf file. In my case **myIcons.ttf** I renamed **name and fontFamily** to **myIcons** in selection.json

Comment: have you added "rnpm": { "assets": [ "resources/fonts" ] }, this line to your package.json file ??